# Decomposing a tensor in terms of matrices and bases

Tags: tensors

I want to represent a 3D cartesian Tensor T of order m x n x p as a sum of 2D tensors and bases.

If I slice T in the first dimension:

$$T_{1::} = \begin{pmatrix}
T_{111} & \cdots & T_{11p} \\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots \\ 
T_{1n1} & \cdots & T_{1np}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to represent $T$ as

$$T = T_{1::}u_0 + ... + T_{m::}u_m $$

I think $u_1 = \sum_{n, p}  e_1 \otimes e_n \otimes e_p$ but I am unsure?

Similarly, if I slice it in the middle dimension:

$$T_{:1:} = \begin{pmatrix}
T_{111} & \cdots & T_{11p} \\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots \\ 
T_{m11} & \cdots & T_{m1p}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I would also like to decompose T like so:

$$T = T_{:1:}v_1 + ... + T_{:n:}v_p $$

How do I represent the basis vectors $u$ and $v$ above?

Comment: How do you define a product like $T_{1::}\ u_1$?

Comment: @VladimirLysikov Good question: whatever definition provides the correct representation

Comment: Well, for a matrix $M=(m_{ij})$ and a vector $u=(u_k)$ we can define their tensor product $M \otimes u$ as an order 3 tensor with components $t_{ijk}=m_{ij} u_k$. Then $T = \sum_{k = 1}^p T_{::k} \otimes e_k$ where $T_{::k}$ are slices of $T$ and $e_k$ are basis vectors. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes that's it - thanks!